# Why my Program isnt working after providing input?

Tags: c, input, gets

My program isnt working just after I provide input , i also tried giving input from other ways too , like gets [ Where it gave warning of buffer overflow ] , with fgets [ program exited with error code 0 ] and same in scanf as fgets. What should I do to overcome this issue? :

[For example this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NAwv.png)

Comment: There's a tag for `gets`?!

Comment: I guess it's time to head to meta and check out the burninate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example code you sent, it doesn't seem that the program have any error with getting the input.

What your program does is get the input, process it, and then end, with return code 0. I believe that the problem in your code is that you are not printing any output, so you don't actually know that the problem succeeds.
From the message in CLion, it seems that the program is ending as expected, with return code 0.

To fix this issue, make sure to print the result in the end of the function, and see what the result is.
For example, add the following code to the end of the function (between line 31 and line 32):

> printf(string2);